# R - Convert various csv numeric columns to date

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I have a csv datasheet with 7 columns filled with numeric values.
3 of these columns represent the date of the measurements: `"YYYY", "MM", "DD",` followed by 4 columns of relevant corresponding data: `"qobs", "ckhs", "qceq", "qcol"`.

How do I convert the three first columns filled with numeric values into a date-datatype, while maintaining the dependency of the dates to the corresponding date?

```
#   YYYY, MM, DD, qobs, ckhs, qceq, qcol
# 1 1981, 1, 1, 7.136, 0, 0, 0
# 2 1981, 1, 2, 6.76, 0, 0, 0
# 3 1981, 1, 3, 10.886, 0, 0, 0
# ...
```

I looked online and only found solutions using the `as.Date` function that correspond to a single character string. I'm fairly new to programming and have only used R for a couple of days, so an elementary explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, @VincentJs, welcome to SO. There's a proper way to ask for help here, so, please, take a moment to read the post linked here. You'll need: provide some reproducible data, your potential problematic code (or a description of your problem) and your expected output.  https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a specific `lubridate` function for this:

```
# Toy data
aux <- tibble::tribble(
  ~YYYY, ~MM, ~DD,  ~qobs, ~ckhs, ~qceq, ~qcol,
  1981,   1,  1L,  7.136,     0,     0,     0,
  1981,   1,  2L,   6.76,     0,     0,     0,
  1981,   1,  3L, 10.886,     0,     0,     0)

# lubridate::make_date
aux <- mutate(aux, date = make_date(year = YYYY, month = MM, day = DD))

# Output
> aux
# A tibble: 3 × 8
   YYYY    MM    DD  qobs  ckhs  qceq  qcol date      
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1  1981     1     1  7.14     0     0     0 1981-01-01
2  1981     1     2  6.76     0     0     0 1981-01-02
3  1981     1     3 10.9      0     0     0 1981-01-03
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tiydverse` solution:

```r
library(vroom)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) # a truly wonderful package for this kind of thing

df <- vroom("path-to-your-file.csv"
            col_types = "iiidddd")

df <-
  mutate(
    df, 

    date = make_date(YYYY, MM, DD)

   .keep = "unused", # drop the columns used for computation
   .before = qobs
   )
```

#### Explanation

[`vroom::vroom()`](https://vroom.r-lib.org/) is a really useful (and really fast!) function for reading plaintext data into R. It guesses the delimiter from the data and is generally pretty easy to implement.

[`dplyr::mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) is a staple of [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) data manipulation. It computes new columns within dataframes, or modifies existing columns by overwriting them with new values. Here, we are computing a new column called `date` using [`lubridate::make_date()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/make_datetime.html), which does what it says on the tin.

We also specify some of `mutate()`'s named arguments:

- `.keep = "unused"` lets us automatically drop all of the columns we used to calculate our new variable, because we no longer need the `YYYY`, `MM` or `DD` columns
- `.before = qobs` just makes our new `date` column appear in front of `qobs`, on the left-hand-side of our dataframe.

---

**Edit**: I was previously implementing the convoluted:

```r
paste(YYYY, MM, DD, sep = ",") |>
lubridate::ymd()
```

Thanks to Adriano for showing me that `make_date()` exists!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a date format variable using the `YYYY`, `MM`, and `DD` variables together. Below are two solutions, one using base R and the other using the lubridate package.

```
df <- data.frame(
  YYYY = c(1981, 1981, 1981),
  MM = c(1, 1, 1),
  DD = c(1, 2, 3),
  qobs = c(7.136, 6.76, 10.886),
  ckhs = c(0, 0, 0),
  qceq = c(0, 0, 0),
  qcol = c(0, 0, 0)
)

# Using as.Date()
df$asDate <- as.Date(paste(df$YYYY, df$MM, df$DD, sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

# Using ymd()
library(lubridate)
df$ymd <- ymd(paste(df$YYYY, df$MM, df$DD, sep = "-"))
```

From the variable you have created, you can retrieve back the information for the year, month, day and other (see [`lubridate` documentation](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_lubridate.pdf)).

```
year(df$ymd)
#> [1] 1981 1981 1981
month(df$ymd)
#> [1] 1 1 1
day(df$ymd)
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: @VincentJS the call to `lubridate()` here is equivalent to my solution, but without using `mutate()` - reading them both may help you to understand how `mutate()` operates.